# Spring batch job is running automatically on project startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I've developed spring batch job which gets the data from JDBC. The problem I'm facing, it's executing on project startup regardless of `enabled_property`. The value of the property is **FALSE**. I've tried to create a conditional bean on `property` but it didn't also worked and job is being executed on project startup.

Following the my code snippet.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "wallet-manager.djeezyConfig.enableJob" , havingValue = "false")
public Job createJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("DJeezy wallet cleaner job")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(Step1())
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "wallet-manager.djeezyConfig.enableJob" , havingValue = "false")
public Step Step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("DJeezy wallet cleaner job - step1")
            .<ResellerWallet,ResellerWallet> chunk(wConfig.getDjeezyConfig().getChunkSize())
            .reader(resellerWalletItemReader)
            //.processor(resellerWalletProcessor)
            .writer(resellerWalletItemWriter)
            .faultTolerant()
            .skip(EmptyResultDataAccessException.class)
            .build();
}
```

I've also tried to commented the `@Scheduled` annotation but it stills executing the job and steps.

//@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 15000)
public void scheduleByFixedRate() throws Exception {

```
if(config.getDjeezyConfig().isEnableJob()) {

    System.out.println("Batch job starting");
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addString("time", format.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())).toJobParameters();
    jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    System.out.println("Batch job executed successfully\n");
}
```

}

Can someone please guide me what I'm missing here? and how can I prevent my job and step being executed on startup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

hope you are using this property in your properties file
this should work